# Открыть новое окно при нажатии кнопки в PyQt5 (Qt Designer)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qdialog

Я использую *Qt Designer* для создания своего приложения. Есть главное окно `MainWindow` и форма `Dialog`, которую я хотел бы открывать по нажатию кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я должен написать метод (возможно, не в **main.py**, как я полагал, а в разметке) открывающий эту форму диалога и как он должен выглядеть?

При создании приложения есть **2** файла: **`1`**. Разметка **uidesign.py** и **`2`**. Логика работы виджетов **main.py**

**main.py** (кратко, без импортов)**:**

```
 class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() # Экземпляр класса Ui_MainWindow, в нем конструктор всего GUI.
        self.ui.setupUi(self) # Инициализация GUI
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openDialog) # Открыть новую форму

    def openDialog(self):
       pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(219, 62)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "click me"))


class ClssDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClssDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClosed)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.pushButton.setText("Close Dialog")

    def btnClosed(self):
        self.close()


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() # Экземпляр класса Ui_MainWindow, в нем конструктор всего GUI.
        self.ui.setupUi(self)     # Инициализация GUI

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openDialog) # Открыть новую форму

    def openDialog(self):
#       pass
        dialog = ClssDialog(self)
        dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWin()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]